# Find projects which belong to several categories

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a `projects` table (columns `id` and `name`), a `categories` table (columns `id` and `name`) and a join table `projects_categories` (columns `project_id` and `category_id`).

I want to write a query that returns all the projects which belong to a set of categories. For instance if I have

```
projects
id name
1  foo
2  bar
```

```
categories
id name
1  bee
2  gee
```

```
projects_categories
project_id category_id
1          1
1          2
2          1
```

I want to write a query that returns me the project "foo" if I pass the category ids 1 and 2. I have tried the following query, but it it returns all the projects that belongs to category 1 OR 2, not category 1 AND 2.

```
SELECT "projects".* 
FROM "projects" 
INNER JOIN "projects_categories" ON "projects_categories"."project_id" = "project"."id" 
WHERE "projects_categories"."category_id" IN (1, 2)
```

The following query does not return any result:

```
SELECT "projects".* 
FROM "projects" 
INNER JOIN "projects_categories" ON "projects_categories"."project_id" = "project"."id" 
WHERE "projects_categories"."category_id" = 1
  AND "projects_categories"."category_id" = 2
```

I understand why these queries return these results, but can't figure out how to write the query I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with `EXISTS` :

```
SELECT "p".* 
FROM "projects" "p" 
WHERE EXISTS ( 
    SELECT *
    FROM "projects_categories" "pc" 
    WHERE "pc"."category_id" IN (1, 2)
      AND "pc"."project_id" = "p"."id"
    GROUP BY "pc"."project_id" 
    HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT "pc"."project_id" ) = 2)
)
```

Or `JOIN` :

```
SELECT "p".* 
FROM "projects" "p" 
JOIN ( 
    SELECT "pc"."project_id" 
    FROM "projects_categories" "pc" 
    WHERE "pc"."category_id" IN (1, 2)
    GROUP BY "pc"."project_id" 
    HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT "pc"."project_id" ) = 2)
) "tpc" ON "tpc"."project_id" = "p"."id"
```

Or `IN` :

```
SELECT "p".* 
FROM "projects" "p" 
WHERE "p"."id" IN ( 
    SELECT "pc"."project_id"
    FROM "projects_categories" "pc" 
    WHERE "pc"."category_id" IN (1, 2)
    GROUP BY "pc"."project_id" 
    HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT "pc"."project_id" ) = 2)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the query was looking into the same table and column and attempting to have two different values.  This will separate the two different conditions, and then combine them into one result set.

```
SELECT  A.ProjectName, A.CategoryId, B.CategoryId 
FROM    
(SELECT P.Name [ProjectName], PC.CategoryId, PC.ProjectId 
     FROM   @Projects P
            INNER JOIN @Project_Categories PC
                ON PC.ProjectId = P.ID
     WHERE  PC.CategoryId = 1
    ) A
    INNER JOIN (SELECT  P.Name [ProjectName], PC.CategoryId, PC.ProjectId
                FROM    @Projects P
                        INNER JOIN @Project_Categories PC
                            ON PC.ProjectId = P.ID
                WHERE   PC.CategoryId = 2
               ) B
        ON A.ProjectId = B.ProjectId
```